# How iterate a Groovy List with Java?

Tags: java, groovy

I have the following **Groovy** domain class:

```
class A {

  def lotOfBs = []

}
```

Now, from a **Java** class I need to iterate that array. These solutions did not work:

```
for ( B b : a.getLotOfBs() ){
  //COMPILATION ERROR
}

for ( int i = 0 ; i < a.getLotOfBs().length ; i++ ){
  //LENGTH ATTRIBUTE DOES NOT EXIST OR IT IS NOT VISIBLE
}

for ( int i = 0 ; i < a.getLotOfBs().size() ; i++ ){
  //SIZE METHOD DOES NOT EXIST
}
```

Do you have any suggestions?

Thanks in advance

Comment: What does the Java compiler *show* the type of `getLotsOfBs` as?

Comment: That's because you defined it with def. If you declare the field as a list, the first and third methods should work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The array in groovy class is an instance of java.util.ArrayList, so casting to Collection<T> should work:

```
  Collection<B> bs = (Collection<B>) a.getLotOfBs();

  for (B b : bs) {
    ...
  }
```